# Vi editor: Replacing in all lines except the ones that begin with #

Tags: regex, vi

So i need to edit something in every line except the ones that begin with #,
because they are comments. I need to replace all tabs by +.

I know in Vi I can translate stuff like this:

1,$s/a/A/g , replaces all a's by A

but how do i add the range which specifies all lines that don't start with #?

Comment: What do you need to change?  That's going to affect the answer quite a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `g` (global) ex command does what you want:

```
:g!/^#/s/^I/+/g
```

The general format is **g** *[***!***]* **/***RE***/** *CMD*, where *RE* is a pattern describing all the lines to apply the command to and *CMD* is any ex command.  The optional **!** reverses the sense of the RE, applying the command to all lines that DON'T match.

To get a <kbd>TAB</kbd> character on the line (the `^I` above), you need to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: `^I` can be replaced with simply `\t` (i.e. so the command can be copied pasted and work). ( +1 =) ).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this could be achieved with a macro trick

```
qr/^[^#]<Enter>:s/\t/+<Enter>q
3000@r
```

Record a macro that will move to the next line which doesn't start with a #.  Replace all spaces on that line with a tab character.  Then just repeat that macro several hundred times (or whatever number is large enough for your file)

Comment: well I know there's a tool in Vi to translate stuff, ex:

1,$s/a/A/g   replaces a by A in lines 1 to the end, but how do i add the part about 'all lines that don't start with #' to it? also preferably in 1 line